# How to transfer photos without losing exif data about date

Tags: kde, dolphin, exif

I need to transfer photos without losing exif data about the creation date and the modify date. Why? Explanation:

Using Windows, when I transfer photos from my camera, it preserves the creation date to the access date and modify date, so when I list all the photos with details in a file manager (explorer), I still can see the creation date.

However, using Linux (GNU/Debian with KDE), so using Dolphin as file manager, when I transfer photos, it modifies the access date and modify date to the current time. When I list all the photos with details in any file manager (explorer on Windows, or Dolphin, pcmanfm, thunar, etc), I see the date of the transfer.

I need to preserve the creation date of the photos, so I can organize them without having to check the exif information one by one. I just need to see the creation date in the file manager. Is that possible?

I'm searching for a GUI solution. Making a recursive algorithm in bash would be very easy, however, it wouldn't be a user-friendly solution for my mates at work.

Comment: You've confused two different pieces of metadata.  Exif data is stored inside the bytes of the file.  That is almost certainly still there and not removed by a file manager.  The last-modifed / last-access dates are metadata stored in the file system and more easily (accidentally) changed on any OS - even Windows.

Comment: Interesting! That means the files are not modified. I transfer the photos from the camera to my PC (Debian 11 and Dolphin), and I transfer them directly to the server, a Synology NAS (btrfs file system). Where is this information stored? And how to avoid this change?

Comment: The last-modifed can get mangled between the PC and NAS in the protocol.  I think SCP, rsync, and worst case tar then untar on the NAS would maintain the timestamp.  FTP and other protocols might not transfer the timestamp information.

Comment: EXIF timestamps are completely separate from filesystem timestamps. Do your images have EXIF data?

Comment: I run a script over my photos that transforms names from IMG_123456.jpg to 2022-08-24_10-32-33.jpg based on the exif creation date.  They then show up as I want where ever they are copied.  There is one problem with this though, multiple shots within a second!

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention. There's a tool named ImageMagick that can read the EXIF data https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654709/extract-exif-data-as-text-using-imagemagick

Comment: Yeah, ImageMagick is a very interesting tool. However, what I need is the same Windows behaviour into Linux: when I transfer images, I want to keep the last-modified / last-access dates. In that way, any OS and any file manager will show the creation date of the photo.